# Method not defined for UserDetaildsServiceImpl

Tags: java, spring-boot

Good day am not sure what is going i suspect eclipse but in a UserDetailsServiceImpl it
is defined since i implemented the spring`s UserDetailsService below is is my code

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        String jwt = parseJwt(request);
        if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
            String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);

            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}

private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        return headerAuth.substring(7, headerAuth.length());
    }

    return null;
}
```

this is the line giving headache "UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username)"
Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is not working?

Comment: @Simon Martinelli - So i implemented User details service for which it has loadByUsername method and i overrode it in UserDetailsServiceImpl and when i autowire UserDetailsServiceImpl in my AuthTokenFilter when i try to call loadByUsername on UserDetailsServiceImpl instance it says 'undefined type of user details service impl

Comment: Please add the whole trace of the error. Incidentaly, you could run your project in debug and check if `userDetailsService` is null.

Comment: @Jetto Martinez - it was not on stack trace it was when i hover my mouse over the red underline but i know eclipse has a habbit of showing errors where there is none, i had to allow it to create another method inthe user details service impl and delete the former for it to work

Comment: I can't see how you inject userDetailsService

Comment: I don't know what version of Eclipse you are using or what versions you've used, but I've never seen the behavior you mention. Please, add your whole class. If the IDE is prompting an error, we need to check if there is a syntax error/misspell.

Answer (score 0):

Use

**'@Autowired'**

UserDetailService userDetailsService;